# Django Span Filter in View

Tags: python, django, orm

[My model's ER diagram in here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vjMgv.png)

This is part of my models.py.

```
class Company(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    company_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    ...

class Store(models.Model):
    store_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    store_company = models.ForeignKey('Company', related_name='storecompany')
    store_city = models.ForeignKey('City', related_name='cities', to_field='city_name')
    ...

class Discount(models.Model):
    discount_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    discount_category = models.ManyToManyField(Category, related_name="discountcategory")
    discount_store = models.ManyToManyField(Store, related_name="discountstores")
    ...

class City(models.Model):
    city_name = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=25)

class Category(models.Model):
    category_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    category_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

I want to filter discounts with their city. All discounts have a city. For example I received some city name, "bursa" in "city" variable. And I want to filter all discounts in "bursa" city. Maybe my model isn't right but I don't know.

I tried a lot of filter but I couldn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always start from the model you actually want to get. If you want Discounts, query that model, using the double underscore syntax to traverse relationships.

```
Discount.objects.filter(discount_store__store_city__city_name="bursa")
```

Comment: Works flowless. So don't I need to related_name in view anymore? Are they unnecessary?

Comment: The related_name is not relevant here, no. But you don't need them unless you're unhappy with the defaults. As levi points out, if you do want to change them, you should bear in mind they are the *reverse* relation: so `store_city`'s related name should be `stores`. But the default is `store_set`, so unless you really hate that for some reason - or, more likely, you have a conflict with another field - there isn't much point changing it.

Comment: Oh, got it. Thank you. So I have default related_name "tablename_set". I can use them. I don't need assign one more time. By the way can you change "discount_store__store_city__name" to "discount_store__store_city__city_name"? I don't have a name column.

Answer (score 1):

First, in your class Store, the related_name is not "correct", it should be something like "`stores`" not "`cities`" because `related_name` attribute specifies the name of the reverse relation from the City model back to your model.

Less assume that you changed it.

```
class Store(models.Model):
    store_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    store_company = models.ForeignKey('Company', related_name='storecompany')
    store_city = models.ForeignKey('City', related_name='stores', to_field='city_name')
```

Then, given a city name

```
your_city = City.objects.filter(city_name='city_name')[0]

stores = your_city.stores.all()
discounts = [store.discountstores.all() for store in stores]
```

Comment: I got the point. This time @Daniel Roseman's solution is more elegant. But I will keep that in my mind.